# Get data from php script to javascript and use it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I read [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)  and http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/multidim-arrays.phpbut I can't pull it together...pretty overwhelming and I'm just a beginner (they even say to use AJAX...wow!). Could you help we guyz ?

My situation is :

- I have on php script stored in htdocs xampp apache server ;
- I have a html / javascript set of code in another folder (it's a cordova app)

I want to call my php script from the onload event of the body.

Idealy I'd like to do :

```
function init(){

// some instructions
var myvar;

myvar = result of execution of my_php_script;

//using myvar in some other instructions

}
```

You may see below in the last lines of my JS how I intend to use this "code" decribed above

My Current HTML

```
<body onload="init();">

<div id="map">
</div>

</body>
```

My current JS

```
function init(){
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.public.access.token'
}).addTo(mymap);
}

var myvar = result of execution of php script (a table)
var marker = L.marker([myvar[0][1], myvar[0][2]]).addTo(mymap);

}
```

my current php (this php script works fine right now. I wanna return $row in the javascript var myvar)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

  try {
    $hostname = "SQLSERVER_INSTANCE_1";
    $port = 1433;
    $dbname = "MY_BD";
    $username = "user";
    $pw = "pass";
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }


 $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.COORD");
 $sth->execute();


 /*while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
print $row['lat']. "<br/>";
 }*/

$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['lat'];


?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how this question as it stands is too broad and therefore off topic. Write a tiny php that echos "ok" and call that from a simple jQuery `$.get` to see how it works

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem down. First, you need to encode the PHP data in a format JavaScript understands. A good way to do this is via JSON json_encode.

Next you need to make an HTTP request from JavaScript to the PHP script. To do this you can use Jquery ajax function, and set the data type to JSON.

Comment: Also I might recommend using jQuery for the ajax as its a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Simply mentioning ajax isn't very complete since it is asynchronous